# What is passivity property for a function?

Tags: functions

I'm looking for info about the passivity property of a function.
I've heard about this in a course of "Theory of systems and control"and given definition is:

> f continuos and derivable and with the passivity property:
>   [image]

I've searched Google and in  this stack without finding useful information.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Could you tell us where you heard/read about the passivity property?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, updated.